# Extracting matched sample dataframe from MatchThem

Tags: r, propensity-scores, matching

I am using the R package `MatchThem` to match a dataset that contains 19 control samples and 13 case samples.
After running the `MatchThem` command with nearest-neighbor one-to-one matching without replacement, I see in the summary that the matched sample should now contain 13 controls and 13 cases.
I wanted to extract the matched sample dataset so that I can use other functions on this sample (e.g. survival analysis, summary table with `gtsummary`, etc.), and learned that the `complete()` function serves this purpose.

However, after running the `complete()` function and checking the data frame, I see that this (supposedly) matched sample contains 19 controls and 13 cases, just like the initial dataset before matching!

What is the proper way of extracting the matched sample with 13 controls and 13 matched cases?